# Problems with Silverlight4 dragging from desktop

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have ploblems with Silverlight4 dragging from desktop.
When I host my application on the local IIS Web server the Drop event does not catches, 
but if I run my application in Debug mode it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is need to set value of
param "windowless" to "false"
in the start page of Web project.